# Oracle SQL Developer: Calculating Selectivity

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called FANS that stores demographic information on various people including name, address and DOB. The table itself contains 7,655 rows of data. I have created a single INDEX on the CITY column. I know for a certainty that there are only 40 unique cities in the table and there are no NULL values. I'm trying to run a simple experiment on when the optimizer begins to use the INDEX.

```
SELECT CITY
FROM FANS
WHERE CITY BETWEEN 'APOLLO BEACH' AND 'BRANDON';
```

I learned previous from MySQL that Selectivity = cardinality / number of records * 100% where cardinality would be the number of unique values in the index.

When I run "Explain Plan" in SQL developer, it returns a cardinality of 500. Thus the correct math would be 500 / 7,655 * 100%?

Comment: Maybe the oracle formula is different than the MySQL formula.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:40230704959128

Answer (score 1):

The `cardinality` in the Oracle query plan is the number of rows that the optimizer estimates will be returned by that particular step of the plan.  So, yes, the optimizer is estimating that 500/7655 = 6.53% of the rows in the table will match your predicate.

If the 40 `CITY` values are not uniformly distributed, you would want to have a histogram on the `CITY` column to help the optimizer make more accurate cardinality estimates.